# Why comment cannot execute and ignore by the compileres ,in which header file it's defination exit?

Tags: c++, comments, header-files

I am unable to understand the behavior of comments in C++. Why comment not executed by the compiler , what's the main reason, and in which header file the definition of comment can exit.
Thanks

Comment: Comments are not part of the program, it is there to convey important information ( working, purpose, hazards) of the code written to any and all people reading it. Comments are not declared or defined, simply "commented" using `//` or `/**/` in c++

Comment: Could you explain your question more clearly. What do you expect the compiler to do with comments?

Comment: I want to ask that what compiler link comments to any corresponding header file. In which header files the definition of comment exit. The basic purposes of comments are to improve readability for programmers. But why a block of code that can be commented can't execute by the compiler?

Comment: The compiler interprets all of the content of the source files it is told to process or header files (that effectively gets cut and pasted into a source file by the preprocessor).  The rules of the language specify some criteria for the compiler to ignore some content of the source file (e.g. two `/` in succession results in both those characters being ignored as well as everything else following until a newline is encountered) - and this is called a comment. The main purpose is providing information for humans (e.g. to help understand the code) that the compiler doesn't need to do its job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments (single line or multi lined) are not a part of the executable/ library. It is just in place, basically to document the code and make it easier to understand what's going on. Sometimes when the same source or header file is edited by multiple programmers, the other programmers might not know what a particular statement would do, how much it costs (performance and/ or memory), if it might throw an error and so on. The compiler basically ignores these statements as they are not needed to build the actual compiler output.

C++ has two main comment syntaxes,

- `//`: Single line comments.
- `/* */`: Multi line comments.